# Format float with 2 digits before decimal, 6 after decimal

Tags: python, string

E.g. if I have `1.234` I'd like to format it as `'01.234000`.

I can get:

```
>>> f'{1.234:.6f}'
'1.234000'
```

but I also need a leading digit - how can I specify that within the f-string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formatting specification takes a width before the period, and a zero in front of that to say you want leading zeros instead of leading spaces:

```
>>> f'{1.234:09.6f}'
'01.234000'
```